# Cross domain requests for liferay 6.06 web services

Tags: javascript, web-services, cross-domain, liferay, liferay-6

I'm already able to access json data from liferay web services using this url and with a proper authentication :

```
http://login:password@localhost:8080/tunnel-web/secure/json
```

But I'll need to interrogate this in javascript from another domain name.

I've run into the classic error :

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://my.origin.com/' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I know I have to allow this origin on the server response header which can be done in jsp like this :

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://my.origin.com");
```

The question is, how can I allow this origin for liferay's default webservices ?

**edit :**

I've tried to add a **portal-ext.properties** file with :

```
    axis.servlet.hosts.allowed=
    axis.servlet.https.required=false

    tunnel.servlet.hosts.allowed=
    tunnel.servlet.https.required=false

//empty values are meant to allow any IP...
```

But it doesn't change anything :(

PS : I'm using **liferay 6.06**

Comment: Waht are you using to make the request? AlloyUI or jquery?

Comment: I'm using jquery. But it shouldn't matter, it can also be called from pure javascript with standard XMLHttpRequest object no ?

Comment: try this `response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");` and then let me know

Comment: The problem is, I don't know which file is sending the response since I hit on the "tunnel-web" address so I don't know where to set this header :/

Comment: If you have an apache web server (or similar) in front of liferay, you can set the response header in the proxy pass rules..

Comment: It seems that's what I'm looking for. I'm on an Apache Tomcat server. Can you tell me more about it ? What are the proxy pass rules and how can I edit them ? (as an answer so I can upvote or accept it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to alter Tomcat you have to alter liferay web.xml to enable Cors Filter, follow this post:

[Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383109/access-control-allow-origin-in-tomcat)

But to me the best way is having an Apache Web Server (httpd) in front of tomcat/liferay using proxypass module. Apache server runs as reverse proxy for tomcat.

In the proxypass rule you can setup apache to fill the response with some extra headers.

Refer this big post:

[How to correctly configure a reverse proxy with Apache, to be used for cross-domain AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186045/how-to-correctly-configure-a-reverse-proxy-with-apache-to-be-used-for-cross-dom)